# Is there a 'partial reduce' function in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Is there a standard way of combining existing Scala collection functions to achieve the following? Or is this already defined in some popular extension library like Scalaz?

```
def partialReduceLeft[T](elements: List[T], nextReduction: List[T] => (T, List[T])): List[T] =
  if (elements == Nil)
    Nil
  else {
    val (reduction, residual) = nextReduction(elements)

    if (residual.length >= elements.length)
      throw new Exception("Residual collection from nextReduction function must be smaller than its input collection.")

    if (residual == Nil)
      List(reduction)
    else
      reduction :: partialReduceLeft(residual, nextReduction)
  }
```

The function takes a collection and applies a user-defined function which returns the first reduction, which may consume one or more elements. The method keeps going until all elements are consumed.

The resulting collection may have an equal or lower size to the input collection (I rather unscientifically call this a 'partial reduce left' - for want of knowing the exact term for this type of standard function :)).

My implementation is not tail-recursive, and to be honest, I'd much rather use someone else's code!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is similar method in scalaz: `unfold`.

You could implement your method using `unfold` this way:

```
def partialReduceLeft[T](elements: List[T],
                         nextReduction: List[T] => (T, List[T])): Stream[T] =
  unfold(elements){ es => es.nonEmpty option nextReduction(es) }
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will look into this method later. At first glance though, unfold would appear to be the dual of fold. This would imply creating a collection from an element (or a larger collection from a collection of 1). However, what I am doing is making an equal or smaller collection from a collection. Does that make sense? I have no doubt it does what you state! I'm just saying the wording seems unintuitive, or is it just down to how you use it? I don't have the code in front of me right now :P

Comment: Reading the signature makes sense: the result is indeed a collection, but not of type A (the seed) - instead it's of type B, which is the type your reduction function produces from A. Good application - thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield: Also, take a look at iteratee. It's some kind of generalization on `flatMap`.